# Loop until valid input is reached

Tags: java, while-loop

It executes correctly the first time, but:

1. It keeps printing "Please try again (Y/N)?" no matter what the
   input is after asking to continue.
2. I am unsure if != is appropriate to use for String comparison. I want to say while
   loopChoice "is not" Y or N, keep asking.

   ```
   while(isLoop) {
       // Ask for user input
       System.out.print("Enter hours worked: ");
       hoursWorked = scn.nextInt();

       System.out.print("Enter rate per hour: ");
       payRate = scn.nextInt();
       scn.nextLine();

       // Call functions to compute stuff
       ...

       // Print results
       ...

       System.out.print("\nDo you want to continue (Y/N)? ");
       loopChoice = scn.nextLine().toUpperCase();

       while(loopChoice != "Y" || loopChoice != "N") {
           System.out.print("\nPlease try again (Y/N)? ");
           loopChoice = scn.nextLine().toUpperCase();
       }

       switch(loopChoice) {
           case "Y":
               isLoop = true;
               System.out.print("\n");
               break;

           case "N":
               isLoop = false;
               System.out.println("Terminating program...");
               scn.close();
               System.exit(0);
               break;

           default:
               System.out.println("Your input is invalid!");
               isLoop = false;
               System.out.println("Terminating program...");
               scn.close();
               System.exit(0);
               break;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Don't compare String values using `==`. Use `equals()`.

Comment: What if I want to mean "not equals"?

Comment: Then use `!equals()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how you compare strings in Java.

There is also a logical error in your code, as the string can't be both Y and N at the same time, you have to use `&&` instead of `||`. As long as the choice is neither Y or N, you want to continue the loop. If it is any of them, you want to stop. So `&&` is the correct choice here.

To check if two strings are equal, you have to use `.equals(obj)`

```
while (!loopChoice.equals("Y") && !loopChoice.equals("N")) {
```

The reason for this is that `==` compares object **references**, and two Strings are most often not the same object reference. *(Technically, they can be the same object reference, but that's not something you need to worry about now)* To be safe, use `.equals` to compare Strings.

To avoid a possible `NullPointerException` in other situations, you can also use:

```
while (!"Y".equals(loopChoice) && !"N".equals(loopChoice)) {
```

Comment: I have replaced the line with your first suggestion, thanks. I still have problem #1 though, it still keeps saying "Please try again (Y/N)?" even with correct input.

Comment: @ohtph Have you seen the edit I made? Are you using `&&` instead of `||`?

Comment: Thank you, I have refreshed the page quite late. Marked as accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should compare with String equals

```
while (!loopChoice.equals("Y") && !loopChoice.equals("N"))
```

Also, replace the or operator with and operator

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `loopChoice != "Y"`, since "Y" is a String. Either use:

- `loopChoice != 'Y'`, or
- `"Y".equals(loopChoice)`

Alternatively, use `"Y".equalsIgnoreCase(loopChoice)`.

Case switching is also not possible for Strings if you use Java 1.6 or earlier. Be careful.

Comment: I'm currently on Java 1.7 u51, but thanks for the reminder and for clarifying != can be used for char.

Comment: I have also replaced the switch with if-else-if, since the while-loopChoice check catches what the switch-default does anyway. :)

Comment: That's probably a good idea. Btw., the reason I write "Y".equals(loopChoice) is good just practice to avoid NullPointerException. Consider the scenario where loopChoice is null. Trying to run a method on a null object will result in NPE, whereas "Y".equals() will always work, even if loopChoice is null.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I will get into the habit of "CONSTANT".equals(VARIABLE) to watch out for NPEs. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to know that `OR` Operation will return *true* if one of the two condition is *true* , so logically if you Enter `Y` , `so you ask if the input is not equal Y` so the answer is ***false*** then  you will go to the next part in your condition `if the input not equal N` so  the answer is ***True*** , so your finally result will be (**True || False = True )** and then you will entered to while loop again

so the true condition is (**the input not equal Y && not equal N**)

Answer (score 1):

You have fallen into the common early gap between checking equality of objects versus the values of objects.  (You can see a quick list of string comparison information [here] 
(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/comparestrings.html)

What you wrote asks whether the object *loopChoice* is the same object as the string constant "Y" or the string constant "N" which will always return false. You want to ask whether the value of object loopChoice is the same as the value of string constant "Y".

You could rewrite your code as follows:

```
System.out.print("\nDo you want to continue (Y/N)? ");
// get value of next line, and trim whitespace in case use hit the spacebar
loopChoice = scn.nextLine().trim();


while (!("Y".equalsIgnoreCase(loopChoice) || "N".equalsIgnoreCase(loopChoice)) {
    System.out.print("\nPlease try again (Y/N)? ");
    loopChoice = scn.nextLine().toUpperCase();
}
```

Note, I like to put the constant value first for clarity. The general form for determining whether the value of two strings is the same is  String1.equalsIgnoreCase(String2).

Comment: What exactly is the advantage of `"Y".equals(loopChoice)` over `loopChoice.equals("Y")`? Which is considered good practice?

Comment: No computational difference, I just find that placing the "checked for " condition first helps mentally match the purpose of the boolean fragment.